# Scala: how to begin

Tags: scala

I don't found such topic here. So let's share good books (or just it's titles if it is not free/open) to study scala as a first language and also for advanced developers.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info